# Connect to a multi node Couchbase cluster on Docker in Java

Tags: java, docker, couchbase

I created a first couchbase server with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name db1 -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 couchbase
```

The second server I created without the parameters for port because otherwise docker can't deploy the container:

```
docker run -d --name db2 couchbase
```

Now I can access the web console of the first container and create a cluster with the second container.

The problem is that I can't connect to the created cluster in Java because port 11210 is not published for the second container. I'm always getting a *TimeoutException*. How can I solve this?

Comment: As you can't forward both of your servers to the same port on your host machine you will need to map one of the two to another. You could simply map the second one to 11216 instead. It may not be following the standard anymore but it's basically the only way to go other than creating a shared network for your containers.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your comment. Can you give me a small hint about how I can do this?

Comment: Jaskaranbir Singh posted a nice answer with a more detailed explanation, that should cover it :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `expose` the ports for the second container too, just as you did in first container (those "parameters" are port mappings).

Most likely, you were unable to run the second container with parameters because you tried mapping the same ports as you did in first container; aka, you tried this command:

```
docker run -d --name db2 -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 couchbase
```

This wouldn't work because you cannot use ports that are already being used. So try mapping to different set of ports. For example:

```
docker run -d --name db2 -p 9091-9094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 couchbase
```

Notice how I am now using `9091-9094` instead of `8091-8094`. The above command means: `map ports 8091-8094 from the container to ports 9091-9094 in the host`. Any requests sent to `9091-9094`on host will be forwarded to `8091-8094` inside container automatically.

And then you can connect to your second container by specifying the new ports (`9091-9094`).

I suggest you to check the docker basics, especially the documentation for `port mapping`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and now I'm getting the following error when running the second container: `docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db2 (47e09686e028f42142000d07bb5cb2dbf4134edc14d2046d53b8545b95fd4d67): Bind for 0.0.0.0:11210 failed: port is already allocated.` I understand that I could map port 11210 for the second container to another port but the Couchbase Java SDK automatically accesses this port.

Comment: To make this more clear: If I map the port 11210 by running the second container with `docker run -d --name db2 -p 9091-9094:8091-8094 -p 12210:11210 couchbase` and create a cluster I get [this](https://codepad.co/snippet/skwhOxFP) stacktrace when I run [this](https://codepad.co/snippet/iq8GxKd1) code.

Comment: That port is also being used. Just try some other port. Depending on your OS, there are ways/terminal-commands to find out which ports are being used by what. You can also Google search around those commands if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. In the end I used [vagrants](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/vagrants) to run virtual machines for the Couchbase Servers and now everything works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem by setting up virtual machines for the servers with [vagrants](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/vagrants). This way it is no problem to have multiple Couchbase instances with the same ports.